# HighStocks with Reactjs - Make it occupy full size of div container

Tags: css, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying out React with HighStocks using the HighCharts wrapper for React https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutoria ... react-101/

I am unable to make the HighStocks control occupy full container size when the div container is using 100% width and 100% height and sub-containers having height:calc(100% - 40px);

It would be very helpful if there is a sample or an example that can be shared showing HighStocks occupying full div container size in React using HighCharts wrapper for React.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code snippet?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case in this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-guklh?

Comment: Thank you @AndrewA. and  Sebastian Wedzel for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, I was not clear with the issue I was facing. My concern was that React wrapper for HighCharts/HighStocks was not occupying full **height** of the containing div.

**Reported Issue: HighCharts/HighStock with React was not occupying full height**

> As per Highcharts documentation:
>
> Highcharts/HighStocks - By default (when null) the height is
>   calculated from the offset height of the containing element, or 400
>   pixels if the containing element's height is 0.
>   https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

In case of HighCharts/HighStocks with React, React wrapper is adding a div element and  HighCharts/HighStocks renders within this div so HighCharts/HighStocks picks up the height of this div element.

**Solution:**
Adding below CSS to style the div added by React wrapper resolves the issue. [Without this css style, HighChart/HighStock will revert to default height of 400px and does not occupy the entire height]

```
div[data-highcharts-chart] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Below is working sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hooks-27uvb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark